# Visual Studio editor - highlight changes insert mode w/o indicator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, text-editor

Recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Pro after wiping and upgrading to Windows 10. When editing C#, every time I **highlight** some characters for copy/paste, the cursor changes to a gray rectangle and editor acts as if its in Over-strike mode even though the indicator at the bottom of the window says "INS". So I hit the insert button several times and cycle through "OVR" and back to "INS" and the cursor goes back to "|" and I can paste again. Then the moment I **highlight** some text it happens all over again.  This is very frustrating.  Double clicking the indicator has the same temporary result as the Insert button.

(Note: this is not the same problem as the other when the user was working from a Mac and couldn't change INSERT mode.)

Comment: Have you installed any VS extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Good idea Sam.

I looked at the extensions. It occurred to me that this was reminiscent of the VI editor.  When upgrading I had decided to try VSVIM, the add-in for using the VI editor in Visual Studio.

Uninstalling VSVIM solved this problem.

Thank you Sam!